# Mysql - Select value from 'Show master status' query

Tags: mysql, database-replication

hi
How can i select just the position value from the 'SHOW MASTER STATUS' query
exp something like

```
select position from (show master status);
```

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct table to query that info.

If you use PHP, you can retrieve it as follows:

```php
$sql="SHOW MASTER STATUS";<BR>
$result = mysqli_query($sql);<BR>
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);<BR>
$pos = $row["Position"];
```

If you need it via shell scripting you do the following:

```bash
POS=\`mysql -h... -u... -p... -A -skip-column-names -e"SHOW MASTER STATUS;" | awk '{print $2}'\`
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you Rolando i am writing a shell scipt so i tryed the shell command and and it give me what i am looking for just a small correction in the command for other vesitor (--skip-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

*In Linux you can type the following command in the terminal this will give you the single value of Seconds_Behind_Master.*

```
 mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -e 'show slave status\G' | grep 'Seconds_Behind_Master';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux bash script you can try below command through mysql client to get the File and Position

**For File:**

```
mysql -u username -p password -h IP -P Port -e "show master status" | grep "File"| cut -d ":" -f2
```

**For Position**

```
mysql -u username -p password -h IP -P Port -e "show master status" | grep "Position"| cut -d ":" -f2
```